# Need an example of  not finitely generated graded algebra such that its  Poincaré series is a rational function.

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, co.combinatorics

Is it  possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather obviously yes.

Let $A$ be the algebra over the field $K$ generated by elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots,$
with $a_i$ in dimension $i$ and with $a_ia_j=0$ for all $i$ and $j$.
This is an incredibly uninteresting example, but since each graded piece
is one-dimensional, its Poincare series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n=1/(1-t)$.

Comment: I agree but I am interested with an  algebra with non-trivial multiplication.

Comment: @Melania: how about start as Robin did, and then kill all $a_ia_ja_k$?  

Comment: Yes..The  Poincare series will be $\dfrac{1}{(1-t)(1-t^2)}.$   Thanks!